# Elasticsearch best similarity for retrieving exact matches

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with 1 million phrases and I want to search in the index with some query phrases in italian (and that is not the problem). The problem is in the order in which the matches are retrieved: I want to have first the exact matches so I changed the default similarity to "boolean" and I thought it was a good idea but sometimes it does not work. For example: searching in my index for phrases containing the words "film cortometraggio" the first matches are:

- Distribuito dalla General Film Company, il **film**- un **cortometraggio** in due bobine
- Distribuito dalla General Film Company, il **film** - un **cortometraggio** di 150 metri - uscì nelle sale cinematografiche

But there are some better phrases that should be returned before those ones like:

- Robinet aviatore Robinet aviatore è un **film cortometraggio** del 1911 diretto da Luigi Maggi;

This last phrase should be returned first in my opinion because there is no space between the two words I am searching for.

Using the BM25 algorithm the first match that I get is "Pappi Corsicato Ha diretto **film, cortometraggi**, documentari e videoclip.".  In this case also should be provided the phrase "Robinet aviatore Robinet aviatore è un **film cortometraggio** del 1911 diretto da Luigi Maggi;" because is an exact match and I don't get why the algorithm gives the other phrase a higher score.

I am using the Java Rest high level client and the search query that I'm doing are simple match Phrase query, like this:
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery(field, text).slop(5)

This is the structure of the documents in my index:

```
XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
            builder.startObject();
            {
                    builder.field("id",id);
                    builder.field("frase",frase);
            }builder.endObject();
          IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indice);
          indexRequest.source(builder);
          IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Does anyone know how can I change the similarity criteria to retrieve the matches in the correct order?

Comment: could you show the Query that you're doing?

Comment: I am doing it on java with the rest high level client (but in the end is the same doing it with the rest client or with kibana) and the query are simple match Phrase query

Comment: 1. Which version of elasticsearch are you using?
2. If you do the query using DSL query yo got the same result?
3. I have replicate your scenario in kibana dev tools using a match phrase query with the same slop but my first result is Robinet aviatore Robinet aviatore è un film cortometraggio del 1911 diretto da Luigi Maggi;

Comment: 1)I am using the 7.0.0 version
2)I get the sane result
I did not tell you that I am using an italian analyzer with the "italian" stemmer (not the "light_italian"), maybe that Is the Reason why we get differenti results.

Comment: Sorry, I am using the 7.11.2 version

Comment: Please post your exact query that your are using. Use the _explain API to analyze the scoring. I would combine a match_phrase query with a boost with your normal query. Also take a look at query_string and simple_query_string queries they have a simple DSL that makes testing boolean queries and tuning for boosts easy.

Comment: @samy I edited the question showing the exact query that I am doing and putting the structure of my documents in the index. For every match the score I get i 1.0 since I am doing a matchPhrase query that gives a match only if the matched phrase has all the terms  of the query phrase. How can I use the boost not for the field but for the normal query? And how can I use the boost in the Java API? Because I don't find anything about the boost in the official guide in the Java Rest Client section. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replicated your problem in my ambient, same version, same analyzers but I still received the same results. Probably that is for the BM25 algorithm, the other millions of docs influence the score.

I have some suggestions that could help you to solve the problem:

1. Don't use the full steaming Analyzers because they are too
   intrusive, use the light version
2. You could complement the light analyzer using the *ngram* tokenizer
3. You could create a bool query
   that matches first to the fields without the analyzer using a
   multifield

mapping Example:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "message": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "analyzed": { 
            "type":  "text",
        "analyzer": "my_italian_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the query could be something like:

```
GET italian_example/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": {
              "query": "film cortometraggio",
              "slop": 5
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message.analyzed": {
              "query": "film cortometraggio",
              "slop": 5
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": {
              "query": "film cortometraggio",
              "slop": 5
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": "film cortometraggio"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In this query you boost the particular phrase.

Comment: Sorry, right now It's little bit complicated for me.